# Callrail API HTTP GET request with headers

Tags: jquery, ajax, get

I can throw this into a linux terminal and get results.

```
curl -H "Authorization: Token token={api_token}" \
 -X GET \
 "https://api.callrail.com/v2/a/{account_id}/calls.json?company_id={companyId}"
```

Here is what I have:

```
var myToken = "fakeToken1234";

$.ajax
    ({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://api.callrail.com/v2/a/{accountId}/calls.json?company_id={companyId}",
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function (xhr) { xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization:', + myToken ); }
    });
```

Per [CallRail Documentation](http://apidocs.callrail.com/#authorization) I'm supposed to pass the `api_token` into HTTP Authorization header. I get a `401 Unauthorized` message.

I think my syntax is off but can't pin it down. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was I didn't understand the syntax that CallRail wanted in the header.

This solved it: `headers: { "Authorization": 'Token token=' + myToken },`

```
var myToken = "token1234";
var accountId = "Id1234";
var companyId = "Id1234";     

$.ajax
    ({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://api.callrail.com/v2/a/" + accountId + "/calls/timeseries.json?company_id=" + companyId + "",
        dataType: 'json',
        headers: { "Authorization": 'Token token=' + myToken },
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result);
            },
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would try using "headers:":

```
let companyId = "";
let accountId = "";    
let myToken = "fakeToken1234";
    $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: `https://api.callrail.com/v2/a/${accountId}/calls.json?company_id=${companyId}`,
          headers: {"Authorization": `Token token="${myToken}"`},
          dataType: 'json'
    });
```

Don't forget to also load the companyId and accountId in your url. I am assuming you are using the right url in this answer by the way.

Hope it works. I only did $.ajax requests with one API so far. So let me hear if it works. It should at the very least point you in the right direction.

Comment: headers: { "Authorization": 'Token token=' + myToken },